Detect changes in timeseries, clickhouse
Let say, I have the following table.



vals
created_at




test_1
2024-01-01 22:35:00


test_3
2024-01-01 22:34:00


test_1
2024-01-01 22:33:00


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:59


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:49


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:29


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:26


test_2
2024-01-01 22:22:24


test_2
2024-01-01 22:22:23


test_1
2024-01-01 22:22:22


test_1
2024-01-01 22:20:22



Is it possible to detect changes in vals column based on date order?
I want to detect the new value when it appears.
The desired output is:



vals
created_at
HasChanged




test_1
2024-01-01 22:35:00
1


test_3
2024-01-01 22:34:00
1


test_1
2024-01-01 22:33:00
0


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:59
0


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:49
0


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:29
0


test_1
2024-01-01 22:32:26
1


test_2
2024-01-01 22:22:24
0


test_2
2024-01-01 22:22:23
1


test_1
2024-01-01 22:22:22
0


test_1
2024-01-01 22:20:22
1



I tried the following query, but it didn't help much. Full example can be found here:
https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/809158ff-eee1-4bea-b960-d25b60e3e820
SELECT
    vals,
    created_at,
    lagInFrame(vals) OVER (
      PARTITION BY 
      vals
      order by created_at desc
    ) AS hasChanged

FROM taable
ORDER BY created_at DESC


Detecting changes in values is part of the Gaps and Islands class of problems

here is how you can do it:
SELECT * 
 , case when lagInFrame(vals,1,vals) over (order by created_at) = vals 
   then 0 else 1 end as changed
FROM taable
order by created_at desc

fiddle
